# Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster even after Adding ip 0.0.0.0/0 in the whitelist

Tags: node.js, mongodb, debugging, mongoose, error-handling

Error.message is producing this message :

Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/

[added the 0.0.0.0/0 ip also in the whitelist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtriX.png)

index.js

```
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000

app.use(express.json({ limit: "30mb", extended: true }))
app.use(express.urlencoded({ limit: '30mb', extended: true }))
app.use(cors)

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello there !')
})

const CONNECTION_URL = "mongodb+srv://admin:****@stackoverflow-clone.znaf2pt.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority"

mongoose.connect(CONNECTION_URL, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
  .then(() => app.listen(PORT, () => { console.log(`Server running on PORT ${PORT}`) }))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err.message))
```

Comment: Hey try re-adding the ip 0.0.0.0/0 after the cluster is finished building

Comment: hey thanks for the answer. But the problem was I was using a VPN after I changed the network and it worked fine